# Redirecting a .bat-file-containing-executable's stdout to a file

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file, console-application, redirect, stdout

I have a batch file that calls an executable program. The program (compiled C code) generates some output to stdout. The batch echos some output as well. When running the bat, I use redirection (>) to get the text to a file.

mybat.bat contains:

```
myprog.exe arg1 %1 arg3  
echo Done
```

then, at the console:

`C:\> mybat arg2 > log.txt`

The problem is that in `log.txt` I get only the output of the `echo Done` command and not the output of `myprog.exe`. Without the redirection, I get the expected output on the screen.

Note: Under Windows XP

Update: this gets even weirder. When running `myprog.exe` from the command prompt, I get the expected output to the console. Then, when redirecting its output to `log.txt`, the file is empty! The printing is done using `fprintf(stdout, "...")` or `fprintf(ofp, "...")` where `ofp` is assigned: `FILE *ofp = stdout;`.

Further investigation: it seems like the `fprintf(stdout...` lines where redirected, while the `fprintf(ofp...` are not (yes, the pointer is assigned correctly). I also found that the program crashes at somepoint (at a call to `feof()`). So, my conclusion is that due to the abnormal termination of the program, the standard output buffers were not written to the file. HOWEVER - this happened only for the lines that use the pointer. I guess that these lines have shorter output, so the flush frequency is lower (I used the stdout line to print a deliberate help message).

Once solving the crash problem, the data is now redirected to the log file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is `myprog.exe` using stdout or stderr?

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting both stdout and stderr to the log file.

```
mybat arg2 1>&2> log.txt
```

Comment: thank, it dumps everything to the console instead to the file.

Comment: Try adding the line `xcopy /?` to the batch file and re-run.  If the xcopy help output shows up in the log file, it means myprog.exe is not using standard output streams.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cmd /c "mybat.bat arg2" > log.txt
```